Create a linked list using different constructors
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node* next;

    node()                  //default constructor
    {
        data = 0;
        next = NULL;
    }
    node(int value)         //parameterize constructor
    {
        data = value;
        next = NULL;
    }
};


int main()
{
    node* n = new node();   //no argument
    cout<<n->data<<"->";
    node* n1 = new node(1); //1 argument
    cout<<n1->data<<"->";
    node* n2 = new node(2);
    cout<<n2->data;

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}

I want to make link list with different constructor. I am not understanding what should I do in constructor where I gave next = NULL.problem my next pointer is NULL everywhere. It's not pointing any other block.

Perhaps you should also have a list class that takes nodes and links them together? A single node makes no list, as you have seen.

I recommend the C++ Core Guidelines: ES.60: Avoid new and delete outside resource management functions There is no reason to use new in your code and there is almost no reason to use new in modern C++.

Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform for specific questions. Do you have a specific question? "This is my code. How can I fix it" is not a specific question.

I hope it is for educational purposes. In real code use std::forward_list for a linked list (or std::list for a bidirectional linked list).

Welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer solves your problem you could click '✔' to mark it as an accepted answer. With enough rep you can also upvote any helpful answer (see here: What should I do when someone answers my question?).

First I would like to emphasis that all the following answer is just for learning.
In real code if you need a linked list I recommend to use std::forward_list for singly-linked list, and std::list for doubly-linked (i.e. bidirectional) one.
Some notes for the code following:

You can represent the whole list via the first node in it, which we will call head.

Connecting the nodes can be done by adding an optional argument to the constructors, with a pointer to the previous node.

In modern C++ is it not recommended to use manual new/delete. One alternative is using smart pointers.

But for this toy example you don't even need smart pointers - just allocate the nodes on the stack.

Another good practice is to encapsulate the data members, and allow access to them via accessor methods. And use nullptr instead of NULL (which is a legacy from C).

I also added a method print_list_starting_from_me that prints the whole list starting from a node that represents the head.

methods that do not need to change members of the current object are marked const so that the compiler will enforce that they are indeed not changed.

It's better to avoid using namespace std;. See: What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?


Complete toy example:
#include<iostream>

class node
{
public:
    node(node * pPrev = nullptr) 
        : data{ 0 }, next{ nullptr }
    {
        if (pPrev) pPrev->next = this;
    }

    node(int value, node* pPrev = nullptr)
        : data{ value }, next{ nullptr }
    {
        if (pPrev) pPrev->next = this;
    }

    void print_list_starting_from_me() const
    {
        node const * pScan = this;
        while (pScan)
        {
            std::cout << pScan->data << " -> ";
            pScan = pScan->next;
        }
        std::cout << "[END]\n";
    }

    // Accessors to the data:
    int  get_data() const { return data; }
    void set_data(int d)  { data = d; }

private: // encapsulate data members
    int data;
    node* next;
};


int main()
{
    node head;
    node n1{ 1, &head }; // n1 is the next node after head
    node n2{ 2, &n1 };   // n2 is the next node after n1
    head.print_list_starting_from_me();
}

Output:
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> [END]

Live demo.
